# How to get ListViewItem under MouseCursor while dragging sth. over it

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, drag-and-drop, listviewitem

I'm implementing drag & drop on a ListView. I already managed to get the ListViewItem under the cursor when dropping on it but I would like to get the ListViewItem under the mouse cursor *while* I'm dragging sth. over the ListView-Control.

I would like to select the ListViewItem (selected=true) like in Windows Explorer when you are dragging files over a folder.

I thought about events like ItemMouseHover, MouseMove in the ListView but they are not fired when dragging sth. over it.

Hope you can help me...

Regards,

inno

P.S.: I'm using .Net2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried responding to the DragOver event in the listview class?  You should be able to do it this way.

```
private void listBox_DragOver(object sender, 
  DragEventArgs e)
{
  //for ListView
  var point = listView.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
  var item = listView.GetItemAt( point.X, point.Y);     
  if(item != null)
  {
     //do whatever - select it, etc
  }


  //or, for ListBox 
  var indexOfItem = 
    listBox.IndexFromPoint(listBox.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y)));
  if (indexOfItem != ListBox.NoMatches)
  {
     //do whatever - select it, etc
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, the german short description of DragOver says sth. like: Occurs, if an element is dragged over the borders of the ListView-Control (so I thought DragOver occurs only one time if an element is dragged *out* of the borders of the ListView).
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Seems to detail ListBox information, not ListView information

Comment: @PeterRitchie Yes, it was just ListBox.  Added ListView block as well since that's what the question is for.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing drag and drop in a ListView, you learn a lot by looking at the code of [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx) (an open source wrapper around .NET WinForms ListView).

If you use an ObjectListView instead of a normal ListView, a lot of things, like drag and drop, happen automatically.

Comment: Do I guess right that you are the guy behind ObjectListView (had a short look at your profile at SO and at CodeProject) ;).
Thanks for the hint. ObjectListView looks great!

Comment: Yep. I'm the author. So, I'm biased -- but also accurate in this case :)